# VBA code working when I step through it, but not when it's run

Tags: excel, vba

I have some basic VBA that is allowing a user to take a field from one table and use it to update another table. It works fine when I step through it, but nothing happens when I run it using F5. I don't get any errors, just nothing happens.

I think it could possibly be that the value hasn't been assigned to one of the variables before the next step occurs, but I've never had that problem before, and I've always assumed VBA wouldn't move to the next step until it had completed the one it's on?

My code is below:

```
    Option Explicit

Sub acceptDateComp()

    'set data type
    Dim dtType As String
    dtType = "opportunity"

    'declare sheets
    Dim wsComp As Worksheet
    Set wsComp = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(dtType & "Comp")
    Dim wsBCE  As Worksheet
    Set wsBCE = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(dtType & "Snapshot")
    Dim wsOffline As Worksheet
    Set wsOffline = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(dtType & "Database")

    'declare tables
    Dim bce As ListObject
    Set bce = wsBCE.ListObjects(dtType & "Snapshot")
    Dim offline As ListObject
    Set offline = wsOffline.ListObjects(dtType & "Database")
    Dim dateComp As ListObject
    Set dateComp = wsComp.ListObjects(dtType & "DateComp")

    'declare heights and areas
    Dim offlineRange As Range
    Set offlineRange = offline.ListColumns(1).DataBodyRange

    'check for acceptance, then change values
    Dim i As Long
    Dim dateID As Long
    Dim offlineRow As Long
    Dim bceDate As String

    For i = 2 To dateComp.ListRows.Count + 1
        If dateComp.ListColumns(6).Range(i).Value = "Yes" Then
            dateID = dateComp.ListColumns(1).Range(i).Value
            offlineRow = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(dateID, offlineRange, 0)
            bceDate = dateComp.ListRows(i - 1).Range(5).Value
            offline.ListRows(offlineRow).Range(12).Value = bceDate
        End If
    Next i

    Call opportunityComp

End Sub
```

Comment: First step: add `Option Explicit` to the top of the module and declare all variables. Next step, make sure all `Sheets` calls are qualified with the workbook they are in. Then also be explicit about the `.Value` of a `Range` call.... and maybe step through with F8 to see what's happening as well.

Comment: Thanks, made those changes, but not much progress. The code is now not working when I step through it; everything happens as expected, apart from the `offline.ListRows(offlineRow).Range(12).Value = bceDate` line. Again, no errors raised, but nothing happens either.

Comment: Add the `.Value` on here too: `dateComp.ListColumns(6).Range(i).Value = "yes"`. What happens when you step through with F8?

Comment: Done, no change. That line of the code is already running correctly. When I step through with F8, the IF statement returns `TRUE` so the code within it runs. I've added watches to all the variables, and they all behave as expected. Just nothing happens when that final line runs. Super weird.

Comment: And you don't have an `On Error Resume Next` in the code?

Comment: Nope. I've removed calling the other Sub at the end as well in case that was somehow rolling back any changes, and that's not done it either.